# Will Radiobutton created dynamically have fixed text size in Windows Form c#?

Tags: c#, radio-button

I have tried to create a radiobutton dynamically and add it to groupbox/form, but the whole text associated with the radiobutton is not getting displayed. When the radiobutton is added from the designer, the whole text is getting displayed. For dynamically adding radio button am I missing anything or are there any ways to do it?
Please find the sample code below:

```
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            private void SelectMicrophone_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton r1 = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton(); //created a radiobutton
                r1.Name = "Microphone(RealTex";
                r1.Text = "Microphone(RealTex";
                r1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(15, 15);
                this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(r1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the text property in the designer, it adjust the radio button to the new size to cover the width of the text. By default I think the width is 90 and with the text above it is resized to a width of 124. So when you create the object at runtime, it is probably just keeping the width to 90. You can however just set r1.Width = 124 before adding it to your controls collection.

Keep in mind that you may not know the length each time so you could either set the width to the maximum size that you need or use the TextRender's .MeasureText method to get the size of the text and then just add 20 to that to cover the graphic of the radio button circle that also appears and set the result of the X property to your width before adding the radiobutton to the collection.

```
        RadioButton r1 = new RadioButton();
        r1.Text = "This is short text";
        //Measure the Text property and get the width and add 20 to accomodate the circle
        r1.Width = (TextRenderer.MeasureText(r1.Text, r1.Font)).Width + 20;
        r1.Location = new Point(15, 15);
        this.Controls.Add(r1);

        //Just another RB with even longer text.
        r1 = new RadioButton();
        r1.Text = "This is even longer text that we want to show";
        r1.Width = (TextRenderer.MeasureText(r1.Text, r1.Font)).Width + 20;
        r1.Location = new Point(15, 35);
        this.Controls.Add(r1);
```